# Reliable way to unlock locked synchronize block

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, tomcat, synchronized

Occasionally the system throws a SEVERE error on the synchronized block and there is a try-catch which should, in theory, initiate a thread 'unlock' process however this isn't triggered. I, therefore, can conclude that this is not treated as an exception within the system. Is there a reasonable way of handling said lock?

Consider the following code from `board.jsp`:

```
account = Account.get(accountID);
Object synch=account;

if(synch == null) {
    %>No account.<%
    return;
}
try {
    synchronized(synch) {
        ....
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    ....
} finally {
    ....
}
```

example dump

```
SEVERE: Scheduled tasks not running!
Apr 07, 2020 4:59:36 PM ExecLauncher:execLauncher run
SEVERE: ---------------------
Thread is: "http-bio-8080-exec-18" Id=122 BLOCKED on com.main.Account@5a0b8133 owned by "http-bio-8080-exec-7" Id=38
        at org.apache.jsp.realtime.board_jsp._jspService(board_jsp.java:192)
        -  blocked on com.main.Account@5a0b8133
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
```

Thanks for looking :)

Comment: Firstly, I'd extract any logic from the `.jsp` file.

Comment: You can use the re-entrant locks with Conditions, you will get better control on that, even you can lock and unlock it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out, you will get more control to lock and unlock explicitly using Reentrant locks.

```
account = Account.get(accountID);
Object synch=account;
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();


if(synch == null) {
    %>No account.<%
    return;
}
try {
lock.lock();
    /* Your actual code which you were executing in 
      the synchronized block */
} catch (Exception e) {
    ....
} finally {
    lock.unlock(); // this will work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exception but rather it says that the Thread "http-bio-8080-exec-18" can not execute because it tries to enter the synchronized(synch) block. It can not enter this block because the monitor is currently held by the thread "http-bio-8080-exec-7".

So the first thing is to find out why "http-bio-8080-exec-7" does not release the monitor. This might simply be a performance problem, to many threads are trying to execute tissecition in parallel. Or the thread might be hanging. You can analyze this by generating a thread dump:

To generate a thread dump go to the bin folder of your java installation. There is a tool called jps (jps.exe on windows) Execute this, you will see a number (the pid) and a name of a program. Find your program and execute jstack [pid]. jstack is also in the bin folder of your Java installation.

You then will see what every thread is doing in your program, and what the thread with is currently owning the monitor is doing.

There is a way to wait only a specific time to try to aqcuire a lock. I am not quite sure if this solves your problem but to be complete here it is. Use a reentrant lock together with tryLock:

```
 if( lock.tryLock(long timeout,
          TimeUnit unit))
 { try {
   // ... method body
 } 
 finally {
   lock.unlock()
 } 
 }
 else {
    // lock could not be acquired at the given time
 }
```